# recognize_google fails with WinError 10054

Tags: python, networking, python-requests, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I am trying to run an example i found online for speech to text, but i see that recognize_google is failing:
I get the following error:

```
the surrounding noise level
listens for the user's input
Using google to recognize audio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pvpkumar\PycharmProjects\AI_Jedai\aud_inp_reco.py", line 41, in <module>
    MyText = r.recognize_google(audio2)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pvpkumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\_init_.py", line 840, in recognize_google
    response = urlopen(request, timeout=self.operation_timeout)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pvpkumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pvpkumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pvpkumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pvpkumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pvpkumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1377, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pvpkumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1352, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pvpkumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1374, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\pvpkumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 318, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pvpkumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 279, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pvpkumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 706, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

# Initialize the recognizer
r = sr.Recognizer()


# Function to convert text to
# speech
def SpeakText(command):
    # Initialize the engine
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(command)
    engine.runAndWait()


# Loop infinitely for user to
# speak

while (1):

    # Exception handling to handle
    # exceptions at the runtime
    try:

        # use the microphone as source for input.
        with sr.Microphone() as source2:

            # wait for a second to let the recognizer
            # adjust the energy threshold based on
            # the surrounding noise level
            print("the surrounding noise level")
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source2, duration=0.2)

            # listens for the user's input
            print("listens for the user's input")
            audio2 = r.listen(source2)

            # Using google to recognize audio
            print("Using google to recognize audio")
            MyText = r.recognize_google(audio2)
            MyText = MyText.lower()

            print("Did you say ", MyText)
            SpeakText(MyText)

    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("unknown error occurred")
```

What is the reason? Are there any alternatives to recognize_google i can? it seems to fail only with a vpn connection, what setting should i look for to make sure it works with VPN.

it seems to fail only with a vpn connection, what setting should i look for to make sure it works with VPN.